# Setup django on AWS EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2

I am trying to host a django app on AWS EC2 for learning purpose (on ubuntu-8.04.3). 
I get "**It Works**" message on requesting `http://ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
But I don't get the admin page. Below are the steps I followed:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/',include('django.contrib.admin.urls')),
)
```

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS=(
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes'
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin'
)
```

mysite configuration:
*location: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
    ServerName  mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /home/demo/mysite

    Alias /static /home/demo/mysite/template/static/
    <Directory /home/demo/mysite/template/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/demo/mysite/media/
    <Directory /home/demo/mysite/media>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/demo/mysite/mysite.wsgi
    <Directory /home/demo/mysite>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**mysite.wsgi:**
*location: /home/demo/mysite/*

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('home/demo/mysite')
os.environ['DJANG0_SETTINGS_MODULE']='mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

`syncdb` went well. But I am not getting the admin page when requesting `http://ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com/admin` though it is included in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `URLS.py`. Where am I going wrong? I am getting the `The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.` message.

Comment: Just an aside. If you are trying to set some something up for demo/learning purposes, you might want to use an OS version that isn't scheduled to be end-of-lifed within the next few months.  Might want to look at using 12.04.

Comment: @MikeBrant yes. I followed a tutorial and ended up in older version. I will try the latest version definitely after this. This is my first step. :) BTW, any clue on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you getting Django's 404 or Apache's? Sounds like it's the Apache 404 to me...Do you get the same thing on the local host? Also, everything seems fine in your setup, so you may want to restart the server and see if that makes difference...

Comment: @MarioGudelj It is Apache's 404. Not Django's. No change even after restart. Looks like django is not detected by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error:

```
  <VirualHost *:80>
```

Assuming you cut and pasted that code in. You should probably run that handy apache utility that checks your config files for errors, or read the apache log files.

Comment: Sorry I did not copy paste. It was a typo here. I can enable the Virtual Host using the command `a2ensite`.

Comment: Edited the question. Any other idea?

Comment: Have you checked the apache log files? The "It works" message comes from Apache, not Django, and so there's no sign that your virtual host is applying at all. Maybe your wsgi script isn't executable? Check the apache error log files. Also, check the apache error log files.

Comment: Yes even I have the same doubt. I am not getting the django welcome page that we used to get in localhost. Let me try reading the log file, but am a newbie.

Comment: "It works" message is from Apache. I did not receive Django's Welcome page or 404 error page.